# jQuery UI formating sections content when resizing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using a custom accordion script and the issue that I have is that when resizing the browser it will format the content in one of the sections. I want the content to stay intact and that the scroll bar will take care if you want to see the content. In my demo you will see the issue on section 3.

I try to do overflow: hidden, but if I do it on the ui content it eliminate the scroll bar. I also did the overflow hidden on p but still not working as I wanted. Thanks in advance.

Here is [my Demo](http://codepen.io/amb1s1/pen/absxH)

Here is the HTML code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">body{font:62.5% Verdana,Arial,sans-serif}</style>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="file_wrapper">
        <div class="file_inner">

<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3><div>
<span class="diff"><p>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p></span>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<span class="diff"><p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </span></div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3><div>
<span class="minus"><p>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </span></div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3><div>
<p>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p>
<p> </p>
<p>################################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. GOOD *** Check up/up state for all interfaces excluding tunnel       #</p>
<p># Test 2. GOOD *** BGP neighbor not active                                     #</p>
<p># Test 3. GOOD *** BGP adv and routes check                                    #</p>
<p># Test 4. GOOD *** Show IP OSPF Neighbor                                       #</p>
<p># Test 5. GOOD *** GLBP tested correctly                                       #</p>
<p># Test 6. GOOD *** Verify WCCP is running correctly                            #</p>
<p># Test 7. GOOD *** All pings were succesful                                    #</p>
<p># Test 8. GOOD *** Environmental status                                        #</p>
<p>################################################################################</p>
            </div>                </div>                                                                                                    
              </div>
              </div>

      <div class="file_wrapper">

        <div class="file_inner">
<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3><div>
<span class="diff"><p>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p></span>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<span class="diff"><p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </span></div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3><div>
<p>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p>
<p></p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. </p>
<p># Test 2. </p>
<p># Test 3. </p>
<p># Test 4. </p>
<p># Test 5. </p>
<p>##############################################################################</p>
            </div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3><div>
<p>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</p>
<p> </p>
<p>################################################################################</p>
<p># Test 1. GOOD *** Check up/up state for all interfaces excluding tunnel       #</p>
<p># Test 2. GOOD *** BGP neighbor not active                                     #</p>
<p># Test 3. GOOD *** BGP adv and routes check                                    #</p>
<p># Test 4. GOOD *** Show IP OSPF Neighbor                                       #</p>
<p># Test 5. GOOD *** GLBP tested correctly                                       #</p>
<p># Test 6. GOOD *** Verify WCCP is running correctly                            #</p>
<p># Test 7. GOOD *** All pings were succesful                                    #</p>
<p># Test 8. GOOD *** Environmental status                                        #</p>
<p>################################################################################</p>

                </div>                                                                                               
              </div>

</body>
```

and here is my jQuery:

```
 /* $(function() {
            $( ".accordion" ).accordion();
            //$( "#accordion2" ).accordion();
        });
        */
       $(document).ready(function(){

           var $accordions = $('.file_inner');

           function accordion_expand_all()
           {
               var sections = $accordions.find("h3");
               sections.each(function(index, section){
                   if ($(section).hasClass('ui-state-default') && !$(section).hasClass('accordion-header-active')) {
                       $(section).click();
                   }
               });

           }

           /*
           function accordion_collapse_all()
           {
               var sections = $accordions.find("h3");
               sections.each(function(index, section){
                   if ($(section).hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
                       $(section).click();
                   }
               });
           }

             */


        $('.file_inner').accordion({
            active: true,
            beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {

                // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
                if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
                    var currHeader  = ui.newHeader;
                    var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
                    // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
                } else {
                    var currHeader  = ui.oldHeader;
                    var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
                }
                // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
                var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

                // Toggle the panel's header
                currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top',!isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected',((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

                // Toggle the panel's icon
                currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s',!isPanelSelected);

                // Toggle the panel's content
                currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active',!isPanelSelected)
                if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp('fast'); }  else { currContent.slideDown('fast'); }


                var $this = $(this);

                if (!$this.hasClass('programatic')) {
                    var active = $this.children('.ui-accordion-content').index(ui.newPanel);
                    var $otherAccordions = $accordions.not($(this));

                    $otherAccordions.addClass('programatic');
                    $otherAccordions.accordion('option', 'active', active);
                    $otherAccordions.removeClass('programatic');
                }


                return false; // Cancels the default action
            }

        });
        accordion_expand_all()


       })
```

Answer (score -1):

all you can do is in css try doing this:

```
div{position:absolute;left:(somepixel)px;top:(somepixel)px;}
```

basically if you give width:100% and height:100% for your root element(i.e html document) it will automatically resize it according to width available.

Comment: and do not give width and height in percentages...it creates a litle trouble when you resize your browser

Comment: try not to use percentages in this
 body { 
           color: #111; 
           line-height: 1.5; 
           margin: 0 auto; 
           padding: 0; 
           width: 90%; 
           height: 100%;
           font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
           background: #f9f9f9; 
}

Comment: but I want the page to resize what I don't want to resize is the content(the paragraph inside section 3)